# How to get a Student ID card with picture for Swedish teenagers not yet attending university

Tags: paperwork, fees-and-charges, identity-cards, swedish-citizens

In several countries (e.g. Egypt and India) many venues (e.g. museums) have substantial discounts for "students". How carefully the student status is checked varies greatly, but at many places the guard insists on being shown a Student ID card with picture. Lacking that, the teenagers must pay as adults.

My three daughters are teenagers (ages 14, 15 and 17), two of them attend primary school (grundskolan) and one attend high school (gymnasiet).
So, as of yet, none of them study at a university.

Can I get some Student ID card that will be accepted internationally?

I have not been able to find anything myself. Primary school is compulsory by law in Sweden, so strictly speaking it is redundant to require any student id for Swedish children of primary school age, but this argument is rarely accepted. Passports proving their age does not help.

[ISIC](https://www.isic.org/) requires attendance at a university.

[Studentkortet](https://www.studentkortet.se/appar/) is the closest I have found. It is an app that can be registered for high school students, but this has been refused on several occasions on the basis that it lacks a picture (the fact that it is an app probably did not help either).

I haven't found anything for primary school pupils.

(It is of course entirely possible that these guards are just running a racket where they profit by being overly zealous about this rule, but it would be much easier to argue with them if we had something resembling a real card)

Comment: Are you sure ISIC requires university? I have had an NUS card (UK equivalent) since sixth form (end of Secondary School). And their website says "The ISIC is only available to full time students, so you must be able to prove you are currently studying full time at school, college or university" https://www.isic.org/faq/

Comment: @skifans The form at https://www.isic.se/bli-medlem-och-bestall-ditt-id/checkout-form/ only has university level schools to choose from, but apparently you can apply with other schools, so I'll try that.

Comment: In some countries, it's common for high schools to issue their own ID cards, but apparently not in Sweden, so what about making your own card and laminating it? Every student ID looks significantly different anyway, so it's not as if a museum worker in India has any basis to object to it. And they are genuine students, so you're not trying to get any unauthorized discounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @skifans pointed out, I was wrong to assume that [ISIC](https://isic.se) require university attendance. The reason I thought so was that their online dropdown for schools only showed universities, but it is possible to type any name into that textbox, so I entered the primary school name there.

As proof of attendance, I submitted a screenshot from my daughter's profile page in SchoolSoft (a common online school admin tool in Sweden), and that was accepted.

It is no longer possible to get a physical ISIC card in Scandinavia. There is only a virtual card that can be shown using the ISIC app. I hope that will be accepted by future guards.

Comment: While the school is called 'primary' in Sweden, the schools for teenagers their age would be 'middle school', junior high, or secondary school in many other countries.